# How to OrderBy ASC or DESC a specific column in LINQ according to parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I am generating a `result` using the following LINQ query:

```
var field = "FirstName"; // or "LastName"
var type = "asc"; // or "desc"

var result = (from x in db.ContactSet
              select new
              {
                  x.FirstName,
                  x.LastName
              }).ToList();
```

I need to `orderby` `asc` or `desc` (based off the `type` variable) for the `field` variable.

How can I do this in a clean way?

**EDIT:** The question referred to by the duplicate does not answer this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet)

Comment: If you know the fieldnames on compile time, why would you specify the sorting column name as dynamic?

Comment: I only know them at runtime, I just put that there for simplicity of the question.

Comment: I would stick to the solution @markoJuv gave,

Comment: By the way, second answer in duplicate question is exactly the same as the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/)

Then you can write something like this...

```
var field = "FirstName"; // or "LastName"
var type = "ascending"; // or "descending" <-- full 

var result = (from x in db.ContactSet
          select new
          {
              x.FirstName,
              x.LastName
          }).ToList();

result = result.OrderBy(field + " " + type).ToList();
```

Comment: The type arguments for method <Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type argument explicitly.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle The answer requires [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/)  _(like he explained)_

Comment: I had to head out quickly so I can only check this out when I get back again in two hours. Didn't realize I needed a package. Thanks for clarifying.